# Excel - Calculate average across months, starting from month in cell reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, moving-average, array-formulas

I have a sheet where each row is one user, column O shows the date the user record was created, columns R to AE show the number of logins each user has per month, June 2017 to July 2018.

The goal is to only calculate an average of logins for months >= the month the user was created. If the user has a Created On date value less than 1 June 2017, average all the monthly columns R to AE.

Example 1: A user was created on 24 November 2017, therefore I only want to average logins of the month columns from November 2017 onwards.

Example 2: A user was created August 2013, therefore I want to average all month columns (June 2017 to July 2018, R to AE).

I tried using Index Match, though can't figure out how to  select the range.

[Link to file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iUwreD36lVbJk2H9PVZsZuu_ahobe8h4/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why not use a PivotTable?  ...no formulas required.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write & post their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `=SUM(R2:AE)` to add the logins to get total login.

Use `=DATEDIF(A2, "July 2018", "M")` to get the number of months. First argument of `DATEDIF` is initial date, second argument is final date and `"M"` signifies that we want number of months as the output

Divide the total login by number of months to get the average.

[link to google sheet file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JAm81pOqAd_NyT75fmP5VqFO509m_EEz6pqXgVkr8sI/edit?usp=sharing)